# Which function should be disabled/enabled in php.ini for web hosting servers?

Tags: vps, web-hosting, ubuntu-12.04, php.ini

I have a VPS (Ubuntu 12.04) and I'm testing it for hosting services. Currently the VPS is running only one website for testing, so which function should be disabled/enabled in php.ini so that I can make it more secure?

Hosting Panel = Zpanel

OS            = Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Sorry, but it's impossible for us to give a blanket Answer. The way you use your server and secure it will dictate it's configuration.

Comment: well i have all basic server security setup & i have lots of function disabled in php.ini & may be i m missing something .....i have asked the so that you guys have more experience than me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend:

```
safe_mode = On
expose_php = Off
Enable_dl= Off
magic_quotes = On
register_globals = off
display errors = off
disable_functions = system, show_source, symlink, exec, dl,
shell_exec, passthru, phpinfo, escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd
```

But you might not want `safe_mode = On`. With safe_mode some PHP extensions are disabled, and some software doesn't work, such as Joomla and Drupal.

Comment: Please format so it is more readable.

Comment: @vonbrand there's an edit button under every post for a reason